# Visual Studio 2017 Solution Explorer is empty

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I open an existing VS2015 solution file in VS2017, Solution Explorer is empty. I've tried to close and reopen Visual Studio several times, but the same thing happens every time. How to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

This should fix it:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Open **Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017** (from Windows start menu)
3. Run `devenv /updateconfiguration`
4. Reopen Visual Studio

Comment: This did not fix the issue for me. I am opening a VS2015 solution from the pinned items in the Windows 10 task bar. Very disappointed with VS2017 so far.

Comment: @VinnyBrown I've seen another suggestion to delete .suo file(s). I've not tried that myself, so if you try it and it works, you can post a second answer.

Comment: Eivind Gussiås Løkseth  Nope, that didn't fix it. Seems this might be a problem with a corrupted MEF Cache (according to their documentation). I guess I'll have to wait for a fix. I can get the solution to open sometimes. Unfortunately, the same methods don't seem to work consistently. Sometimes I'll use the Open File icon, other times I'll open it from File/Open. Pretty disappointing from such a usually solid development tool.

Comment: This did not work for me either.  Double clicking on solution or opening from "most recent" list do not work.  Opening from File menu does work.

Comment: devenv /updateconfiguration worked for me.  My VS2017 version is VisualStudio/15.0.0+26228.9. .NET is 4.6.01586.

Comment: this worked for me without having to delete my *.suo file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same issue. VS goes through all the steps when loading a solution, including "Preparing Solution", but then the Solution Explorer just comes up empty. So far I haven't found a solution. I tried deleting .suo files, and I tried cleaning the solution.

Like Eivind, I need to open the solution from the file menu. Fortunately, that has always worked for me so far.

Comment: The solution I gave Mar 8th worked for me. Tip if you've still got this issue: There's a small update available today. Maybe it'll fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Today's update for VS2017 fixed it for me. Also see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24529/solution-doesnt-open-in-vs-2017.html

Answer (score 0):

I faced this type of issue when opening project on visual studio 2017.

If you have connected with TFS and I believed that your connection has been lost.

Re-connect and close the project and then reopen using visual studio.

Hope this will helpfull!

Answer (score -1):

On the Notification Area there is a message for Visual Studio 2017 updates. Click on that and this fixed my problem of empty Solution Explorer when u click on a 2015 sln file.

[image]