# Winforms app missing files in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, solution-explorer

When I try to create a windows forms app in C# in visual studio and the project opens, I don't
find any files in the Solution Explorer.

I doubted that something wrong happened when installing Visual Studio, so I reinstalled my
Windows operating system and then visual studio, but the problem still exists.

I searched a lot but didn't find similar problems like this. I attached some helpful screenshots that also include the installed components.

Thanks in advance to those who will help me.

[image: Installed components in Visual Studio] [image: The app I want to create] [image: The solution explorer is empty]

At first, I tried to reinstall visual studio, then I reinstalled my Windows operating system and then visual studio, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Are any files created on the disk where you create the solution? Maybe a filesystem access issue?

Comment: How does it look in the filesystem. All files there? If not try a "dotnet new winforms" on a console if that creates a complete project.

Comment: If the code file for the form exists - it must as you have it open - then I assume that what's happening is that the project is not being added to the solution even though it exists. Don't know why that's happening but, as a workaround, you should be able to right-click the solution and add a an existing project, then select the project file.

Comment: could you please check where the files are located and how does it look like and share some screen shot?

Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42683317/7261924  may help please check

Comment: Please open the cmd command window and enter “dotnet --info” and press Enter. Take the full screenshot of the message that pops up in your post.

Comment: I opened the cmd command window and entered “dotnet --info”, and the result :
Host:
  Version:      7.0.5
  Architecture: x86
  Commit:       8042d61b17

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the dotnet environment variable is automatically added when Visual Studio and related environments are installed using the Visual Studio installer. However, multiple dotnet environment variables may appear because a previously installed environment has not been fully uninstalled or for other reasons.

You can fix this issue with the following steps:

1. Open the environment variables of your computer and check whether there are more than two dotnet paths in Path, as follows:

[image]

[image]

2. At this time, you need to check your real dotnet path, and then delete the redundant ones. This is my correct path

[image]

3. Then open CMD again and enter "dotnet --info", then the SDK will display normally

[image]

4. Finally, please reopen Visual Studio and you should be able to see your project

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can create the project easily.

Answer (score 1):

What is your Windows type:

I saw this kind of problem in another program. If your Windows is Home, it cannot see folders that are longer than 128 characters. It is possible that you have installed your Visual Studio in a path that you cannot see the relevant files when you want to create a new project.